# TensorFlow Object Detection API print objects found on image to console

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to return list of objects that have been found at image with *TF Object Detection API*.

To do that I'm using `print([category_index.get(i) for i in classes[0]])` to print list of objects that have been found or `print(num_detections)` to display number of found objects, but in both cases it gives me list  with 300 values or simply value `[300.]` correspondingly.

How it`s possible to return only that objects that are on image? Or if there is some mistake please help to figure out what is wrong.

I was using *Faster RCNN* models config file and checkpoints while training. Be sure it really detects few objects at image, here it is:

[image]

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

PATH_TO_CKPT = 'frozen_graph/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

PATH_TO_LABELS = 'object_detection/pascal_label_map.pbtxt'

NUM_CLASSES = 7

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
  (im_width, im_height) = image.size
  return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape(
      (im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR = 'object_detection/test_images/'
TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = [ os.path.join(PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGES_DIR, 'image{}.jpg'.format(i)) for i in range(1, 2) ]

IMAGE_SIZE = (12, 8)

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    img = 1
    for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
      image = Image.open(image_path)
      image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
      plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
      plt.imsave('RESULTS/' + str(img) + '.jpg', image_np)
      img += 1

      # Return found objects
      print([category_index.get(i) for i in classes[0]])
      print(boxes.shape)
      print(num_detections)
```

Which gives following result:

```
[{'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'chesterfield_blue', 'id': 1}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_gold', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'chesterfield_red', 'id': 2}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_red', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_blue', 'id': 3}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'marlboro_mentol', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'lucky_strike_red', 'id': 4}]
(1, 300, 4)
[ 300.]
```

Thanks in advance for any information!

**UPD:**

Thousand thanks for everyone who helped with this question.
Following line of code is exactly what I needed, it gives me list with objects that were found so I can do other operations on them.

```
print [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can see you have 300 detections. `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` shows very few of them because `min_score_thresh=.5` (this is the default value) is too high for the most of them.

If you want to add such filtering to the output you can write:

```
min_score_thresh = 0.5
print([category_index.get(i) for i in classes[0] if scores[0, i] > min_score_thresh)
```

You can change `min_score_thresh` to choose threshold value you need. It may be useful to print the score values with the category names.

Comment: oh, I think thats it, I caught the main idea... I will try to figure out a little bit later, but first try gave me this error `IndexError: only integers, slices (':'), ellipsis ('...'), numpy.newaxis ('None') and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`, did u try your code?

Comment: ok, I have modified just a little bit your code, and following statement gives me exactly what I needed `print [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]`

Answer (score 5):

From the function signature [`visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L323), you have to set the arguments `max_boxes_to_draw`, `min_score_thresh`,

```
visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(image,
                                          boxes,
                                          classes,
                                          scores,
                                          category_index,
                                          instance_masks=None,
                                          keypoints=None,
                                          use_normalized_coordinates=False,
                                          max_boxes_to_draw=20,
                                          min_score_thresh=.5,
                                          agnostic_mode=False,
                                          line_thickness=4)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your hint but unfortunately results are same even with these attributes.

Comment: The question is what are the probabilities of the detected classes?

Comment: @Dat Tran No, I just want to return list or dictionary of objects that were detected, but with code I posted above it gives me dictioanary with 300 values, however there only few detected obejcts on image

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Sure it only gives you a few detected objects because not all the values in the dictionary are really displayed. This depends on the probability threshold.

Comment: @Dat Tran my goal is to print to console only that number of objects or list of objects that is exactly found at image. I cant understand why **num_detections** returns ***300*** value or **[category_index.get(i) for i in classes[0]]** returns list with 300 values in it. Is it possible somehow to return list with number of objects that were found on image exactly?

Comment: I have no knowledge of this specific architecture, but is the issue not something along the lines of it's detecting 300 possible objects, but the scores associated with most of them (the confidence in prediction) are low, so they're not being plotted?  Is scores also length 300?  If so, print out the two of them and the boxes and see if the ones getting drawn are just the ones with a high score.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the *min_score_thresh* to 0. Then you will probably see 300 detections.

Answer (score 0):

open visualization_utils.py and add-->  `print(class_name)` after

```
else:        
 class_name = 'N/A'
      display_str = '{}: {}%'.format(
          class_name,
          int(100*scores[i]))
```

this will print the detected objects

Answer (score 0):

adding `print(class_name)` after

```
else:        
 class_name = 'N/A'
      display_str = '{}: {}%'.format(
          class_name,
          int(100*scores[i]))
```

in `visualization_utils.py` file prints the detected object.
I wonder where to add print command to print timestamps as well as percentage of accuracy in output.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this will load the labels and categories along with category index

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)

categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)

category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)


//to print the identified object do the following :
```

print category instead of category index. The index holds the numeric value and the category contains the name of the objects. Once identified with the mentioned threshold the

```
min_score_thresh = 0.5

print([category.get(1)] for i in classes[0] if scores[0, i] > min_score_thresh)
```

this will print the identified category.