# Extracting the detected class name - tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

My question is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674696/tensorflow-object-detection-api-print-objects-found-on-image-to-console) extremely informative thread. I was to take this a step further and print only the detected class name.

As answered in the thread,I am currently able to obtain: `[{'id: 4 , 'name': 'bottle'}]` using the code line `print[category_index.get(value)`

I have been trying to isolate just the classname detected so that I can print an output that is simply `bottle` on the terminal.
What changes would I need to make in my print line to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def GetClassName(data):
   for cl in data:
    return cl['name']

#data processed

data = [category_index.get(value) for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.9]

print(GetClassName(data))
```